# Windows 7 - "Magic" frequent folder

Tags: windows-7

Every week, I export an mp3 file from audacity into a folder with that day's date (e.g. this past sunday I exported the file to a folder named 20130609). Then I close everything and that's it for a while.

Then, I come back a few hours later to upload the file to ftp. I usually have some folders open, so to open a new one, I right click on the folder icon on the taskbar...

[image]

to open a new folder window and browse to this folder I just created, right? Well I look up a little bit and:

[image]

So I click it and upload the file, and it actually saves me 30 seconds, which is really awesome... but what in the world? It happens every single week without fail. I create the folder inside the audacity export window. The folder stays on the frequent list until I create a new folder the following week.

This was definitely not an advertised feature of Windows 7, and it's extremely handy... but it really just seems like magic to me. **How does it work?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides a **Tasks** category, an app's **Jump List** [can include](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msdn10/gg281362%28v=msdn.10%29) **Recent**, **Frequent**, **Pinned** as well as custom categories (also see [this helpful article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/2012/08/27) by Raymond Chen).

As for how it works, give [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20130602085757/http://blogs.microsoft.co.il:80/blogs/sasha/archive/2009/02/20/windows-7-taskbar-jump-lists.aspx) a read:

> What does the Windows Shell consider a recent or frequent item? Well, it’s just a file [*or folder in your case - Karan*], that your application is associated with in the registry (not necessarily as the default handler), and that was either:

> - Used to launch your application directly (e.g. double-clicking a file in Windows Explorer)

- Selected by the user in a common file dialog (open/save)
- Specified as the parameter to the SHAddToRecentDocs API function

The second is most likely what applies to your case, and thus the folder you've selected in Audacity's Save dialog gets added to Win Explorer's Jump List. Helpful certainly, but magic? Not quite. :)